# How many different battle pet types are there in Mists of Pandaria?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm a huge Pokémon fan and found that they are adding the battle pet system in Mists of Pandaria.

How many different **TYPES** of battle pets are there? (I understand that there can be different skins for the same type purely for aesthetic values)

What are their abilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ten, with corresponding strengths and weaknesses.  I have just confirmed this in the beta:

[image]

Their strengths and weaknesses are as follows:

1. Beast - takes 50% more damage from mechanical; takes 33% less damage from humanoid
2. Critter - takes 50% more damage from beasts; takes 33% less damage from elemental
3. Dragonkin - takes 50% more damage from humanoid; takes 33% less damage from flying
4. Elemental - takes 50% more damage from aquatic; takes 33% less damage from mechanical
5. Flying - takes 50% more damage from magic; takes 33% less damage from beasts
6. Humanoid - takes 50% more damage from undead; takes 33% less damage from critter
7. Magical - takes 50% more damage from dragonkin; takes 33% less damage from aquatic
8. Mechanical - takes 50% more damage from elemental; takes 33% less damage from magical
9. Undead - takes 50% more damage from critter; takes 33% less damage from dragonkin
10. Aquatic - takes 50% more damage from flying; takes 33% less damage from undead

Individual battle pet skills have different postives/negatives in terms of doing damage to different pet types, so that isn't determined by the type themselves.

[image]